# How do I expose my Rails App to an external source for authentication using Sorcery?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, google-chrome-extension, sorcery

I have a rails app that stores my user information and data using the Sorcery gem, and I would like to have a chrome extension I am working on, authenticate with my rails app.

I cannot seem to find any references to an API in Sorcery which would allow me to authenticate using my user database from an external source.

How do I expose my sorcery-powered rails app as an oauth server, such that I can store a key, which I can attach to my javascript application when I make an AJAX to my api.

Is it possible to do so, and/or what is the best practice for cross-site authentication? Like how should I store the authenticated user information etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know if sorcery supports token authentication.

[devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) does, and it's really simple:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Simple-Token-Authentication-Example

Comment: [TokenAuthenticatable has been removed from Devise.](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2739)